# PYGAME sprites will not spawn in a new location

Tags: python, pygame

okay, so the object of the game is to run over the Parcel. this will show you what item the parcel contains, and where to take it. after you drop off the parcel to the location, the idea is to have a new randomly generated item and location for the next parcel. my problem is that the item and location will not seem to spawn to a new location, just roll random the first time, and keep spitting back that same item and location. can anyone help me out?

here is my code

```
#Initialize
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

#Display
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1180, 900))

class PaperBoy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,startY):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("paperboy.gif")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.rect.centery = startY
        self.dx= 300
        self.dy= 300


    def update(self):

        #adjust x/y to dx/dy

        self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx+self.dx
        self.rect.centery = self.rect.centery+self.dy



        #check Boundaries

        #Check right
        if self.rect.centerx >= 670:
            self.rect.centerx =670
        #Check left
        elif self.rect.centerx <= 220:
            self.rect.centerx = 220
        #Check Bottom
        if self.rect.centery >= 700:
            self.rect.centery = 700
        #Check Top
        elif self.rect.centery <= 200:
            self.rect.centery = 200



    def moveUp(self):
        self.dx=0
        self.dy=-5

    def moveDown(self):
        self.dx =0
        self.dy =5

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.dx =-5
        self.dy = 0

    def moveRight(self):
        self.dx =5
        self.dy =0



class Parcel(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("parcel.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (430,420)

"""
    ================================HUD======================================
"""
#Green Y 
class ItemHUD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("itemhud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (1020,200)

#Red A
class WhereHUD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("where.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (1020, 450)

#Small Green
class TimeHUD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("timehud.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (915, 850)


#Yellow
class GoldHUD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("gold.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (1020, 620)


"""
    ==============================PARCEL OBJECTS==============================
"""
class Potion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("potion.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (950, 200)

class Book(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("book.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (950, 200)

class Net(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("net.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (950, 200)

class Pendant(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pendant.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (950, 200)

class Tunic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("tunic.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (950, 200)



"""
   ===================================Rupees==================================
"""

class GreenRupee(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("GreenRupee.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

class BlueRupee(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("BlueRupee.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

class RedRupee(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("RedRupee.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

"""
   ------------------------------------HOUSES---------------------------------
"""
class H23(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("23.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (920, 620)

class Indicator23(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("indicator.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (370,274)

class H24(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("24.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (920, 620)

class Indicator24(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("indicator.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (224,406)

class H25(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("25.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (920, 620)

class Indicator25(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("indicator.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (655,480)

class H26(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("26.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (920, 620)

class Indicator26(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("indicator.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (310,695)

class H28(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("28.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (920, 620)

class Indicator28(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("indicator.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = self.image.convert()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (655,680)

"""
   ------------------------------------MAIN-----------------------------------
"""
def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption("A Link to the Parcel")
    background = pygame.image.load('village.png').convert()

    allSprites=pygame.sprite.Group()

    #ITEMS
    potion = Potion()
    book = Book()
    net = Net()
    pendant = Pendant()
    tunic = Tunic()

    #HEADS UP DISPLAY
    itemHud = ItemHUD()
    timeHud = TimeHUD()
    goldHud = GoldHUD()
    whereHud = WhereHUD()

    indicator23 = Indicator23()
    indicator24 = Indicator24()
    indicator25 = Indicator25()
    indicator26 = Indicator26()
    indicator28 = Indicator28()


    goldSack = 0

    #HOUSE NUMBERS
    """
    h23 = H23()
    h24 = H24()
    h25 = H25()
    h26 = H26()
    h28 = H28()
    """

    packages = [Potion, Book, Net, Pendant, Tunic]
    packagetype = random.choice(packages)
    indicators = [Indicator23, Indicator24, Indicator25,
                  Indicator26, Indicator28]
    indicatortype = random.choice(indicators)
    #Player
    paperboy = PaperBoy(200)
    parcel = Parcel()
    package = packagetype()
    where = indicatortype()
    #Sprites added to AllSprites Group
    allSprites.add(paperboy)
    allSprites.add(parcel)
    allSprites.add(itemHud)
    allSprites.add(timeHud)
    allSprites.add(goldHud)
    allSprites.add(whereHud)

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                    paperboy.moveUp()
                elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    paperboy.moveDown()
                elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    paperboy.moveLeft()
                elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    paperboy.moveRight()
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, parcel):
            if packagetype == packages[0]:
                allSprites.add(package)
                allSprites.add(where)
                allSprites.remove(parcel)
            elif packagetype == packages[1]:
                allSprites.add(package)
                allSprites.add(where)
                allSprites.remove(parcel)
            elif packagetype == packages[2]:
                allSprites.add(package)
                allSprites.add(where)
                allSprites.remove(parcel)
            elif packagetype == packages[3]:
                allSprites.add(package)
                allSprites.add(where)
                allSprites.remove(parcel)
            elif packagetype == packages[4]:
                allSprites.add(package)
                allSprites.add(where)
                allSprites.remove(parcel)

        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, where) == True:
            allSprites.remove(package)
            allSprites.add(parcel)
            allSprites.remove(where)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, where) == True:
            allSprites.remove(package)
            allSprites.add(parcel)
            allSprites.remove(where)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, where) == True:
            allSprites.remove(package)
            allSprites.add(parcel)
            allSprites.remove(where)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, where) == True:
            allSprites.remove(package)
            allSprites.add(parcel)
            allSprites.remove(where)
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paperboy, where) == True:
            allSprites.remove(package)
            allSprites.add(parcel)
            allSprites.remove(where)

        fontTitle = font.render("A Link to the Parcel", True, (255,255,255,))


        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fontTitle, [925,25])


        allSprites.clear(screen, background,)
        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code:

in the update method of the player class do something like this:

```
if self.rect.colliderect(parcelLocation):
    parcelLocation.kill()

    newparcel = Parcel((random_x, random_y))
    newLocation = Location((random_x, random_y))
```

in the Parcel and Location sprite class give them a parameter called pos and so that when they get the `(random_x, random_y)` they will be put at this random location each time a new one is instantiated

hope this helps a bit

Good luck! :)